# How to buffer PhantomJS's /dev/stdout output so that PHP exec can get it whole?

Tags: php, shell, laravel, pdf, phantomjs

I have PhantomJS script that takes some arguments and generates PDF from a given URL (URL is one of the arguments). Script works fine and physically stores PDF.

What I want to achieve is to skip storing those PDF as files, I want to generate them "on fly / on demand" and pass them to Phantom's `/dev/stdout`.

Why? Because then, in Laravel (where I trigger the whole script with `exec`) I will get the binary output, I will add proper headers for PDF files and will allow user to download generated file.

Making long story short:

This is part of my script:

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load URL ' + address);
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });
            phantom.exit();
        }, 400);

    }
});
```

It's saved on the server as `foo.js`:

When I trigger it directly in CLI by executing:

`phantomjs /home/vagrant/Code/test/scripts/foo.js http://google.com`

Then I get:

[image]

which is absolutely great because that's the content of desired PDF. Take a look at the last line:

`%%EOF`

When I run the same command in Laravel 5.1:

```
$test = exec('phantomjs /home/vagrant/Code/test/scripts/foo.js http://google.com');
dd($test);
```

Obviously my favourite L5 command (`dd`) prints just the last line:

[image]

Finally time for my question: **How to modify page render `std` output to buffer it somehow so that `$test` will get everything (all lines)?** Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! Changing `exec` to `shell_exec` seems to solve the problem. Now `dd()` prints the whole binary content.

Comment: Could you share the rest of your PHP script? Principally the part who output the pdf to the browser?
Thanks a lot